# Display and count killed enemies in Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity3D and I am trying to count all the enemies I have killed on runtime and display in `OnGUI()`. What I did was that for every time the enemy is killed, I am going to increment: `enemyKilled`. However, when it does... some time in the program... the display decrements and then disappears.

```
public class ShootableBox : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator anim;
    public int currentHealth = 3;       
    public int enemyKilled;         // Count how many enemies you have killed           
    public float currentHealthLength;

    bool isSinking;                     // To trigger the dead enemy to sink
    public float sinkSpeed = 1f;        // Sink speed

    void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        currentHealthLength = Screen.width/2;
        enemyKilled = 0;
    }

    void Update ()
    {   
        // If the enemy should be sinking...
        if(isSinking)
        {
            transform.Translate (-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }       
    }


    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        //subtract damage amount when Damage function is called
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;

        //Check if health has fallen below zero
        if (currentHealth <= 0) {
            enemyKilled = enemyKilled + 1;
            //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it 
            anim.SetTrigger ("isDead");
            //transform.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ().Stop ();

            // Find and disable the Nav Mesh Agent.
            GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ().enabled = false;

            // Find the rigidbody component and make it kinematic (since we use Translate to sink the enemy).
            GetComponent <Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;

            Invoke ("StartSinking", 2.5f);

        } else {
            anim.SetTrigger("isHit");
            anim.SetTrigger("isRun2");
        }
    }

    public void StartSinking() {

        // The enemy should now sink.
        isSinking = true;
        // After 2 seconds destory the enemy.
        Destroy (gameObject, 8f);
    }

    // My problem is somewhere on this part
    public void OnGUI() {

        GUI.contentColor = Color.yellow;

        if (enemyKilled != 0) {

            GUI.Box(new Rect(5, 5, currentHealthLength, 20), "Enemies killed: " + enemyKilled );
        }
    }
}
```

I can already kill the enemy on runtime. I just can't seem to display the correct number of enemies dead right. How can I fix this error? Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: Is this script attached to your enemy? (or shootable box in this case)

Comment: @Mr.Bigglesworth yes, i have.

Comment: You're attaching this script to the player or to the enemies? This makes huge difference.

Comment: @m.rogalski to the enemies..

Comment: @WandaMaximoff avoid the use of OnGUI, rely instead on the new UI system provided by Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script is on every enemy so you will get each enemy have a different score and it will try to output that to the GUI.

On top of that you actually destroy the object in the StartSinking function, yet it is responsible for displaying the GUI so that will stop once destroyed.

The script responsible for keeping score should be on some form of GameManager class which can't be destroyed or it would lose count. There should also only be one so it keeps an accurate score.

For example you have a class called GameManager and it is attached to a gameobject in the scene. It doesnt matter what kind of gameobject it can just be empty. This is the class that should keep score and display it to the screen.

The enemy script should only be responsible for and control what the enemy does so take out the GUI calls. When an enemy dies you call the GameManager class and tell it that another enemy has died and it can update its score.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour{

private int enemyKilled= 0;

  public void UpdateScore()
  {
     enemyKilled++;
  }

   public void OnGUI()
   {
     GUI.contentColor = Color.yellow;
     GUI.Box(new Rect(5, 5, 20, 20), "Enemies killed: " + enemyKilled );
   }
}
```

Above is an example manager to increase the score each time the UpdateScore method is called. Then it has a OnGui function to display the score.

All the enemy needs is a reference to the GameManager script so you can call the method. This is easy and there are a few methods of doing it. Either make a variable of the type GameManager and search the scene for it or better yet look into creating a static GameManager which can be accessed at all time (the singleton method).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does that help or make sense, if not I am happy to explain or offer examples

Comment: I'm trying to understand it. Would it be okay for you to give an example? Thank you so much.

Comment: So i'm basically going to assign a new script to an empty game object and whenever an enemy dies, i'm just going to have to call `GameManager` and it will update the score. I didn't think calling a function from another script is possible. I'm going to try this one now.

Comment: The simplest and best way to do this is to create an `EnemyContainer` game object, then child all the enemies objects to it when instantiating them, and get the reference to the container script inside the enemy script, by using `enemyContainer = transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyContainer>();` inside `Start()`, whenever an enemy is killed you just call the method using `enemyContainer.UpdateScore()`.

Comment: @Wanda Maximoff yes that's right and yes you can access other scripts in Unity. Using Galandil's example you can use the get component method to get a reference to the script. Scripts count as components on game objects.  There are lots of approaches and none that are wrong.

Comment: Hi. So i should place all the enemy game object under "EnemyContainer" and in my ShootableBox script which is attached to every enemies, I will call the UpdateScore() function? Did I get it right? I apologize and thank you so much.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff Yes, exactly, you swap `enemyKilled = enemyKilled + 1;` with `enemyContainer.UpdateScore();`

Comment: UPDATE: I finally understood it and it's working now. Thank you so much @Mr.Bigglesworth.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff Now you can go wild and expand the concept by using actual scores for different types of enemies. For example, A scores 10 and B scores 20. All you need to do is to add a parameter in `UpdateScore(int score)` to the method, which will have `totalScore += score;` instead of the `enemyKilled++;` line, and then inside the enemy script you declare a `public int scoreValue;` (so you can assign it in the Inspector), and then you call the method by writing `enemyContainer.UpdateScore(scoreValue);`. ;)

Comment: @Wanda Maximoff That's great to hear!! Hope you have fun making the rest of it. Sounds like Galandil is even more excited than you! ;)

Comment: @Mr.Bigglesworth It's always a nice thing when someone learns something new. And I think that pushing them in the right direction in order to expand their knowledge is a good thing too. :>

Comment: I agree completely. +1 for that comment.